# scala parallel collections degree of parallelism

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Is there any equivalent in scala parallel collections to LINQ's `withDegreeOfParallelism` which sets the number of threads which will run a query? I want to run an operation in parallel which needs to have a set number of threads running.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

With the newest trunk, using the JVM 1.6 or newer, use the:

```
collection.parallel.ForkJoinTasks.defaultForkJoinPool.setParallelism(parlevel: Int)
```

This may be a subject to changes in the future, though. A more unified approach to configuring all Scala task parallel APIs is planned for the next releases.

Note, however, that while this will determine the number of processors the query utilizes, this may not be the actual number of threads involved in running a query. Since parallel collections support nested parallelism, the actual thread pool implementation may allocate more threads to run the query if it detects this is necessary.

EDIT:

Starting from Scala 2.10, the preferred way to set the parallelism level is through setting the `tasksupport` field to a new `TaskSupport` object, as in the following example:

```
scala> import scala.collection.parallel._
import scala.collection.parallel._

scala> val pc = mutable.ParArray(1, 2, 3)
pc: scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray[Int] = ParArray(1, 2, 3)

scala> pc.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(2))
pc.tasksupport: scala.collection.parallel.TaskSupport = scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTaskSupport@4a5d484a

scala> pc map { _ + 1 }
res0: scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray[Int] = ParArray(2, 3, 4)
```

While instantiating the `ForkJoinTaskSupport` object with a fork join pool, the parallelism level of the fork join pool must be set to the desired value (`2` in the example).

Answer (score 6):

Independently of the JVM version, with Scala 2.9+ (introduced parallel collections), you can also use a combination of the `grouped(Int)` and `par` functions to execute parallel jobs on small chunks, like this:

```
scala> val c = 1 to 5
c: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> c.grouped(2).seq.flatMap(_.par.map(_ * 2)).toList
res11: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
```

`grouped(2)` creates chunks of length 2 or less, `seq` makes sure the collection of chunks is not parallel (useless in this example), then the `_ * 2` function is executed on the small parallel chunks (created with `par`), thus insuring that at most 2 threads is executed in parallel.

This might be however slightly less efficient than setting the worker pool parameter, I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I'm skeptical this would actually gain you anything. I'd need to see benchmark numbers proving it.