# How to control the concurrency on scala parallel collection

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

Since 2.9 , we can create a parallel collection by a single method `par`. It is easy and simple, but how to control the concurrency for the parallel collection ?

Answer (score 5):

On 2.9.1, the following approach worked for me:

```
collection.parallel.ForkJoinTasks
  .defaultForkJoinPool.setParallelism(<number of needed threads>)
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424496/scala-parallel-collections-degree-of-parallelism).