# How to set the number of threads to use for par

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5425354/298389) that you can set the number of threads to use for all .par operations like so:
`collection.parallel.ForkJoinTasks.defaultForkJoinPool.setParallelism(parlevel: Int)`

But is it possible to set the number of threads to use for just one .par call?

Comment: I suppose you could create a separate pool for that, but I don't think that's supported at the moment.

Comment: This doesn't work in 2.10 anymore.

Comment: possible duplicate of [scala parallel collections degree of parallelism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424496/scala-parallel-collections-degree-of-parallelism)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could create a block that sets the parallelism level and then execute specific methods within that block:

```
def withParallelism[A](n : Int)(block : => A) : A = {
  import collection.parallel.ForkJoinTasks.defaultForkJoinPool._
  val defaultParLevel = getParallelism
  setParallelism(n)
  val ret = block
  setParallelism(defaultParLevel)
  ret
}
```

And then call it as such:

```
withParallelism(2) {
  (1 to 100).par.map(_ * 2)
}
```

Comment: I do not like the fact that it changes the global state

Comment: What version of Scala & Java is this, I get compile error `not found: value setParallelism`

Answer (score 20):

In Scala 2.11 you should use parallel collection task support, like this:

```
parallelCollection.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(
    new java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool(parlevel))

parallelCollection.map( ... )
```

See task support [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/configuration.html#task-support)