# How to control the number of parallel processes with .par in Scala?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, sbt

I am using the [`par.map`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html) expression to execute processes in parallel in Scala (SBT).

Consider `list.par.map(function(_))` (I am preparing an MWE). This means that `function(_)` should be applied to all the elements of the `list` in a parallel fashion. In my example, `list` has 3 elements. But Scala executes only `function(list(1))` and `function(list(2))` in parallel, and only afterwards `function(list(3))`.

Is there a reason for this behaviour? Is there a relation with the fact that the programme is executed on a two-core processor? Or how could you impose to execute all three things in parallel?

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/parallel/immutable/ParRange.html#tasksupport_=(ts:scala.collection.parallel.TaskSupport):Unit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scala parallel collections degree of parallelism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424496/scala-parallel-collections-degree-of-parallelism)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has been asked before:

- [scala parallel collections degree of parallelism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424496/scala-parallel-collections-degree-of-parallelism)
- [How to set the number of threads to use for par](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154691/how-to-set-the-number-of-threads-to-use-for-par)

and is well documented:

- http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/configuration.html

what you want is something like:

```
var parallelList = list.par
parallelList.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(
     new scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(parlevel))
parallelList.map(function(_))
```

That said if your running on a 2 core processor you only have two threads (unless the cores are hyper threaded of course) meaning you can't have more than 2 parallel operations at once.

Comment: @Karlo are you satisfied with this answer?