# Set the parallelism level for all collections in Scala 2.10?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, scala-2.10

I understand how to set the parallelism level for a single parallel collection, via the mutable `tasksupport` field (c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5425354/82970).

> How can I set the parallelism level for all new parallel collections in Scala 2.10?

A subsidiary question --- is the `tasksupport` associated to a parallel collection 'inherited' by new parallel collections built out of it? (e.g. with `take`, `map`, etc.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. I looked at the sources briefly and if I understand things correctly, there are three system properties that can be used to configure the default execution context, which seems to be used as default task support. These determine the parallelism level of the task support object.

   - `scala.concurrent.context.minThreads`: Int, minimum parallelism level
   - `scala.concurrent.context.numThreads`: either an Int, to specify the parallelism level to use directly, or a String: an "x" followed by a Double (e.g. "x1.5"), which is then multiplied with `Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors`
   - `scala.concurrent.context.maxThreads`: Int, maximum parallelism level

   The relevant source file (if I followed everything correctly) seems to be [ExecutionContextImpl](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.10.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/ExecutionContextImpl.scala).
2. As for the second part of your question:
   Transforming operations like `map`, `filter` etc. should preserve the task support that has been set on the originating collection. At least the sources look that way. :)
   Most parallel operations are defined in [ParIterableLike](http://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/collection/parallel/ParIterableLike.scala) and they either call `resultWithTaskSupport` in [Combiner](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.Combiner) (which gets gets the originating task support set via the factory in lines 568 or 581 in ParIterableLike) or set the task support directly on the resulting collection.

Comment: thanks, this is really not well documented and I hate this mutable `tasksupport` property :(

Comment: In a quick test that I've done it looks like as of Scala 2.11.8 the `map`, `filter` etc. operations on parallel collections do not preserve the `tasksupport` and thus parallelism level, which I admit is counterintuitive.

Comment: you'll want to set the task support globally to get around this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865823/how-do-i-set-the-default-number-of-threads-for-scala-2-10-parallel-collections