# Multithreading in scala

Tags: multithreading, scala

I was given a challenge recently in school to create a simple program in Scala the does some calculations in a matrix, the thing is I have to do these calculations using 5 threads, since I had no prior knowledge of Scala I am stuck. I searched online but I did not find how to create the exact number of threads I want. This is the code:

```
import scala.math

object Test{

  def main(args: Array[String]){

    val M1: Seq[Seq[Int]] = List(
      List(1, 2, 3),
      List(4, 5, 6),
      List(7, 8, 9)
    )

    var tempData : Float= 0
    var count:Int = 1
    var finalData:Int=0

    for(i<-0 to M1.length-1; j<-0 to M1(0).length-1){

      count = 1

      tempData = M1(i)(j)+ calc(i-1,j)+calc(i,j-1)+calc(i+1,j)
      finalData = math.ceil(tempData/count).toInt
      printf("%d ", finalData)
    }

    def calc(i:Int, j:Int): Int ={

      if((i<0)|| (j<0) || (i>M1.length-1))
        return 0

      else{
        count +=1
        return M1(i)(j)}
      }
    }
```

I tried this:

```
    for (a <- 0 until 1) {
      val thread = new Thread {
        override def run { 

          for(i<-0 to M1.length-1; j<-0 to M1(0).length-1){

            count = 1

            tempData = M1(i)(j)+ calc(i-1,j)+calc(i,j-1)+calc(i+1,j)
            finalData = math.ceil(tempData/count).toInt
            printf("%d ", finalData)
          }
        }
      }
      thread.start
    }
```

but it only executed the same thing 10 times

Comment: side note : you seem to be adding unnecessary type annotations which hurts readability e.g. `var count:Int = 1` => `var count = 1`

Comment: ok thanks, this is actually my first day learning scala so I dont know all the best practices yet

Comment: `a <- 0 until 1` until is exclusive in its upper bound so the for loop will only execute one time creating only one thread, try to replace `until` with `to` for example and see for yourself

Comment: yes I tried that and it worked, actually the challenge is to create a single thread version and a multi thread version @niceman

Comment: "ince I had no prior knowledge of Scala I am stuck." I think the idea of being at school is to study,  learn, then be able to do new things.  I really don't understand why anyone would take a course, then look for other people to do the assignments for them.

Comment: Like I said this is a challenge, not a course @TheArchetypalPaul. That means I have no lessons in Scala

Comment: "but it only executed the same thing 10 times", well, yes, since that's exactly what you defined it to do. What are you looking to do? If it's parallelise the calculations, you can't just put the whole code in a thread, you need to put individual parts of the calculation in their own thread

Comment: Ok. but "challenge" is pretty much a synonym for exercise or assignment, really. Same thing applies - how does it benefit you to get someone else to meet the challenge?

Comment: Im not asking for you to do the assignment for me, just to give me some "directions"

Comment: OK. Answer coming. BTW, since you only have 9 cells, it's not really possible to use 10 threads. Will the real calculation have a larger matrix?

Comment: Yes, the program will perform the calculations on that matrix and in a 20x20 matrix, this is the actual challenge if you need some details https://github.com/premium-minds/summer-internship-exercise

Comment: "Answer coming. " Will be delayed. Real life intrudes. Hopefully someone else will get there first.

Comment: thanks for the help @TheArchetypalPaul

Comment: Looks like you programming Java in Scala. I am very disappointed see that from a Portuguese institution. :(

Comment: I simply never used scala before, this is a challenge presented by a company in my school to get a summer internship but they gave me the challenge during my exams week so I basically had to learn scala in one day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the original core of the calculation.

```
for(i<-0 to M1.length-1; j<-0 to M1(0).length-1){

  count = 1

  tempData = M1(i)(j)+ calc(i-1,j)+calc(i,j-1)+calc(i+1,j)
  finalData = math.ceil(tempData/count).toInt
  printf("%d ", finalData)
}
```

Let's actually build a result array

```
val R = Array.ofDim[Int](M1.length, M1(0).length)

var tempData : Float= 0
var count:Int = 1
var finalData:Int=0

for(i<-0 to M1.length-1; j<-0 to M1(0).length-1){

  count = 1

  tempData = M1(i)(j)+ calc(i-1,j)+calc(i,j-1)+calc(i+1,j)
  R(i)(j) = math.ceil(tempData/count).toInt
}
```

Now, that mutable `count` modified in one function and referenced in another is a bit of a code smell. Let's remove it - change `calc` to return an option, assemble a list of the things to average, and `flatten` to keep only the `Some`

```
val R = Array.ofDim[Int](M1.length, M1(0).length)

for (i <- 0 to M1.length - 1; j <- 0 to M1(0).length - 1) {

  val tempList = List(Some(M1(i)(j)), calc(i - 1, j), calc(i, j - 1), calc(i + 1, j)).flatten
  R(i)(j) = math.ceil(tempList.sum.toDouble / tempList.length).toInt
}

def calc(i: Int, j: Int): Option[Int] = {

  if ((i < 0) || (j < 0) || (i > M1.length - 1))
    None

  else {

    Some(M1(i)(j))
  }
}
```

Next, a side-effecting `for` is a bit of a code smell too. So in the inner loop, let's produce each row and in the outer loop a list of the rows...

```
val R = for (i <- 0 to M1.length - 1) yield {
  for (j <- 0 to M1(0).length - 1) yield {

    val tempList = List(Some(M1(i)(j)), calc(i - 1, j), calc(i, j - 1), calc(i + 1, j)).flatten
    math.ceil(tempList.sum / tempList.length).toInt
  }
}
```

Now, we read the Scala API and we notice [ParSeq](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/parallel/ParSeq.html) and [Seq.par](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#par:ParRepr) so we'd like to work with `map` and friends. So let's un-sugar the for comprehensions

```
val R = (0 until M1.length).map { i =>
  (0 until M1(0).length).map { j =>

    val tempList = List(Some(M1(i)(j)), calc(i - 1, j), calc(i, j - 1), calc(i + 1, j)).flatten
    math.ceil(tempList.sum / tempList.length).toInt
  }
}
```

This is our `MotionBlurSingleThread`.  To make it parallel, we simply do

```
val R = (0 until M1.length).par.map { i =>
  (0 until M1(0).length).par.map { j =>

    val tempList = List(Some(M1(i)(j)), calc(i - 1, j), calc(i, j - 1), calc(i + 1, j)).flatten
    math.ceil(tempList.sum / tempList.length).toInt
  }.seq
}.seq
```

And this is our `MotionBlurMultiThread`. And it is nicely functional too (no mutable values)

The limit to 5 or 10 threads isn't in the challenge on Github, but if you need to do that you can look at [scala parallel collections degree of parallelism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424496/scala-parallel-collections-degree-of-parallelism/5425354#5425354) and related questions

Comment: The code works just fine except it is giving me the wrong result. it should give me (3,3,4)(4,5,6)(6,7,8) but instead it is giving me (2, 2, 3)(4, 4, 5)(5, 6, 7), this was happening before, I printed the result inside the for loop and it was fine but when I printed the result outside the for loop it gave me the wrong result

Comment: this is the final project, it runs but I cant find the problem I stated above: https://github.com/RodrigoPina407/summer-intership-exercise

Comment: I  just copied your calculation using i and j, but I think you may have some confusion over which is x and which is y. I will leave you to work the correction out :)

Comment: I thought about that but before, the calculation inside the for loop was correct but in the return statement was wrong

Comment: but I will double check, thank you for your help, this was a hard task because the challenge was given during my exams week so I had onoy yesterday and today to learn scala from scratch, thanks again

Comment: I reversed the i and j calculations and I'm still getting errors, but when I trace the calculations by hand it gives me the right results so I dont understand what is happening

Comment: Add lots of printlns! If it works by hand, then I really do think you're getting confused about i, j and x,y. In your head, you're doing the right thing so getting the right answer. In the code, it might be wrong.

Comment: Ah `resultado(x, y) = (M1(x, y)+M1(x-1, y)+M1(x, y-1)+M1(x, y+1)) / 4`. That last term is different from yours. It's `i, j+1`. You have `i+1, j`

Comment: Ok it almost fixed thanks, the only values wrong are the first and the last, thank you for the help

Comment: The readme says to average the pixel+pixel above+pixel below+pixel to the left, as long as they exist so it should be M1(i,j)+M1(i-1,j) +M1(i-1,j)+M1(i,j-1), right?

Comment: In `M1(i)(j)`, which do you think is `x` and which `y`? Once you've decided that, it's a direct translation of the `resultado` definition.

Comment: the i is the y and the j is the x, and the result is correct by doing it this way but it isn't what ir shows, because in my previous implementation the resulto was correct inside the for loop but incorrect in the return statement

Comment: And i tried to put println inside the for loops but it gives an error

Comment: Shouldn't do, as long as it's not the last statement. Remember the last statement must yield the value. So you may need to save the result in a `val` in order that you can print it, then return it as the last value.

Comment: But this is now "normal" debugging. I'm sure you can sort this on your own. And anyway, it's late here :)

Comment: ok I managed to put the println and the values are the same but the calculation are wrong, im trying to figure out why

Answer (score -2):

I am not an expert, neither on Scala nor on concurrency.
Scala approach to concurrency is through the use of actors and messaging, you can read a little about that here, [Programming in Scala, chapter 30 Actors and Concurrency](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/actors-and-concurrency.html) (the first edition is free but it is outdated). As I was telling, the edition is outdated and in the latest version of Scala (2.12) the actors library is no longer included, and they recommend to use Akka, you can read about that [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0-M1#removed-modules).

So, I would not recommend learning about Scala, Sbt and Akka just for a challenge, but you can download an Akka quickstart [here](http://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-quickstart-scala/) and customize the example given to your needs, it is nicely explained in the link. Each instance of the Actor has his own thread. You can read about actors and threads [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/general/actors.html), in specific, the section about state.

Comment: sorry, I really try not to do that, but even if there are newest versions (at a cost) I think the free edition is a common learning resource for Scala developers and most of the concepts are still valid. In this case it was important to say that is outdated because the library is not there anymore, but the approach is still valid using the new Akka library.

Comment: Actors are *one* approach to concurrency in Scala. Parallel collections are another, Futures are another. Stream (Fs2, scalaz.streams) yet another. Not to mention that everything written for Java concurrency is also available. Therefore you answer is wrong.

Comment: I did not say EVER my solution was exhaustive. I started by clarifying that I was not an expert and I still believe it is the recommended approach. Sure you can use everything available in Java but then why not stick to Java, I think you should write an improved answer that enlighten us.

Comment: "Scala approach to concurrency is through the use of actors and messaging, you can read a little about that here,..."

Comment: I think that is valid, if you search for "Scala approach to concurrency" on a search engine you'll get Actors at the top of the results, maybe I should have told the most common approach, or one of many approaches, I did not say it was the only approach either. To say that the approach is something does not imply that any other method is banned, just that it is common practice, and if someone without familiarity with some topic is searching for a quick answer I think support in terms of information available is a good criteria. But I'll really try to be much more specific next time.

Comment: "Scala's approach to concurrency is..." does say to me that you are saying  that is the way to do it. It's also a pretty bad match for the OP's problem. If  you're not an expert in Scala or concurrency, maybe it would be better to move on and answer another question.